# What are the contains of the extended memory obtained using realloc?

Tags: c, realloc

When I use `realloc` to re-size the memory which I used `calloc` earlier to initialize (an array), is it still remains 0 in a whole buffer? or the new part is not initialized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering you're increasing the size of the allocated memory, the *extended* memory region will have indeterminate values.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5, (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of
>   the new and old sizes. **Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have
>   indeterminate values.**

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately `realloc` will not initialize the "new" part that is allocated. So you have to do that yourself. The "old" part will keep its value, though, so if you didn't change that, all your `0`s will still be there.

Comment: I've never thought about this before, but it's a strange asymmetry. You'd think the library would either provide `crealloc`, or not provide `calloc`. It's a bit weird to provide one convenience function, but not the more difficult one to hand-implement.

Comment: @Leushenko what would be the use case? If the memory is being extended, it is suppose to _store_ (_write_) something - why'd you need to initialize it anyway?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think that question applies equally well to `calloc` (I would just remove `calloc` from the library, and make optimizers detect `memset` if need be). If you can justify one, you can justify the other. If you used `calloc` to allocate a large zeroed array and now want to double the size, for instance.